# Почему Linux Firewall не блокирует IP?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, администрирование, firewall

День добрый! 
OS Ubuntu 18.04.
Бот обходит добрую сотню моих доменов которые содержат тысячи страниц, обходит очень агрессивно и создает сильную нагрузку на сервер, до 10 запросов/сек выкачивая в том числе и картинки.

Обычно после анализа логов сразу баню подобных, через WEB интерфейс к панели VestaCP, добавляя правило в Firewall, все очень просто - подсеть, 80,443 порты = готово, запросов после этого не наблюдается.

Сейчас никак не могу забанить назойливого бота, грепаю логи после добавления правил - запросы как шли так и идут. Уже даже добавил UDP / ICMP , все равно запросы идут. Что не так может быть?

```
root@159# iptables-save
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.1 on Sat Sep 29 00:11:25 2018
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [348480:815452129]
:fail2ban-DNS - [0:0]
:fail2ban-FTP - [0:0]
:fail2ban-SSH - [0:0]
:fail2ban-VESTA - [0:0]
:fail2ban-WEB - [0:0]
:vesta - [0:0]
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j fail2ban-DNS
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j fail2ban-WEB
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8083 -j fail2ban-VESTA
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21 -j fail2ban-FTP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j fail2ban-SSH
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s SERVER_IP/32 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 127.0.0.1/32 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 216.244.66.0/24 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j DROP
```

Запросы за несколько часов:

```
root@159# awk '{print $1}' /var/log/apache2/domains/*.log | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head  -n 50 | grep 216.244
  17755 216.244.66.230
  15969 216.244.66.236
  11103 216.244.66.202
  10769 216.244.66.196
   8574 216.244.66.200
   8076 216.244.66.239
```

Comment: Выведи iptables-save. Мне кажется не та цепочка

Comment: добавил iptables-save

Comment: Если для сервера десять запросов в секунду создают серьёзную нагрузку, то вам надо что-то делать с программной частью, ибо это готовый DoS, сэксплойтить который может даже школьник с диалапом. По сути вопроса — предположение только одно: бот каким-то образом попадает в RELATED,ESTABLISHED. Подвигайте блокирующее правило вверх по списку, чтобы увидеть, после которого подъёма оно реально начнёт работать.

Comment: нагрузку с приложения кстати можно снять через bpf - если там настоящий ддос

Answer (score 1):

Перекинь правило в самое начало через -I вместо -A оно отработает до Fail2ban и до эстаблишед. Трафик будет блокирован точно.

Для таких привентивных мер лучше использовать таблицу raw

Comment: Использую Web интерфейс Vesta...остальное же все блокируется, не понимаю почему здесь такая проблема. Есть еще варианты ?